# How do I search words seperated by _ and . in ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and I am very happy with the speed at the moment. 
I still have one requirement that I haven't been able to achieve.

ElasticSearch seems to split the following text when doing indexing:

```
"bmw.co.uk"
"apple_macbook_pro"
```

I am searching in Ruby like this using the ElasticSearch gem:

```
result = client.search index: 'elasticsearch_dev',
                  body: {
                      query: {
                          "bool" => {
                            "must" => {"match" => {"search_text" => {"query" => "bmw", "operator" => "and"}}},
                            "must_not" => {"match" => {"search_text" => {"query" => "", "operator" => "or"}}}
                          }
                      },
                  }
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

When I search for 'bmw' or 'bmw.co', I want records with `bmw.co.uk` to match.

When I search for 'acboo' or 'apple', I want records with `apple_macbook_pro` to match.

How do I go about achieving this?

**Addtional Info**

I have looked at this site, which is along the lines of what I am looking to do, but not quite:

http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html.

If I have the URL:

```
uk-on-sale.com
```

I want this to be tokenized as:

```
[uk, on, sale, com, uk-on, on-sale, uk-on-sale.com, on-sale.com, sale.com, .com]
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `"match_phrase"` query ?

Comment: Yes, that does not achieve the desired outcome